# What do empty parenthesis on a macro achieve?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I've come across a macro in C that I can't work out. The bit I'm confused about is the additional parenthesis at the end of the macro name `myTEST_MARK()`. Does this actually do anything or is it just a naming convention?

```
#ifndef myTEST_FLAG
    #define myTEST_FLAG()
#endif

…

//usage:

if (condition) {
    do something 
} else {
   myTEST_FLAG();
}
```

I understand the basics about text replacement and setting markers/flags, maybe the #defines are here to aid debug later?

Comment: In your case mostly nothing. Probably they just wanted to make it "function-like" macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros can have parameters, since they implement some sort of *inline* function. A macro with empty parenthesis simply emulates a void function.

**But why defining an empty macro in this way?**

Usually this is done in order to have precompiler-level settings. Something like

```
#ifdef SOME_CONFIG_TAG_ENABLED
  #define myTEST_FLAG() doSomething()

#else
  #ifndef myTEST_FLAG
    #define myTEST_FLAG()
  #endif
#endif
…

//usage:

if (condition) {
    do something 
} else {
   myTEST_FLAG();
}
```

The usage remains the same, but if `SOME_CONFIG_TAG_ENABLED` is defined somewhere (in some config.h included file or through -D compiler option) anc actual action is performed, otherwise it is *commented* without changing the caller.

Please note that in the enabled section **you could have not only another macro, but also a function that you might want to completely disable in some cases**. A common example might be:

```
// In .c:
#ifdef STATUS_DEBUG_ENABLED
void TraceStatus(void)
{
  // a lot of printfs tracing the "status"
}
#endif

...

// In .h:
#ifdef STATUS_DEBUG_ENABLED
void TraceStatus(void);
#else
  #define TraceStatus()
#endif

...

// Usage:
if (condition) {
    do something 
} else {
   TraceStatus();
}
```

In this way you can easily compile a debug version that enables all the logs you might want to remove in production version.

Answer (score 2):

A macro defined with parentheses is a "function-like" macro. Occurrences of the macro which do not have arguments will not be recognized and expanded.

There are various reasons for defining a function-like macro with no arguments, rather than an object-like macro.

One reason is that we anticipate that there will be arguments in the future. If we change the macro so that it takes one or more arguments, then the compiler diagnostics will find all the places where the macro is being called without arguments.  If we change an object-like macro so that it now takes arguments, the existing calls are not diagnosed; they just silently stop being expanded.

Another reason is that the macro provides a functional abstraction and could conceivably be replaced by a real function that takes no arguments. We would like to be able to do that just by removing the macro, without having to edit all the invocations to add parentheses.

Consistency plays into this. If the macro is part of some group of related macros that make up an interface, and some of them have arguments, the no-argument ones should look like the others.

Another reason is that the macro expansion does something which has side effects. A macro invocation which looks like `foo;` looks harmless. If it changes the value of a global variable or performs I/O, it's too harmless-looking; if the call looks like `foo();`, then it rightfully looks more suspicious. If we stuff side effects into an expression which looks like `foo;`, then we're using the preprocessor to turn C into another language, which should not be done when easy alternatives allow us to avoid it.